# Requesting User Info with Foursquare API

Tags: php

I am using the `Foursquare API` to request information for my users.

It says to make a request to get user info like this,

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=TOKENHERE
```

So I am doing it like this,

```
$fsUser = file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=".$access_token);
```

When I var_dump I get null from the value I am saving it in, Here is what my full code looks like,

```
<?php
$client_id = "iwdhwouchweohcuwoehcowehcu";
$secret = "ojdwojwjwrhvo";
$redirect = "http://www.example.com";

if($_GET['code']){
//We need to hit up the authkey URL and get the key in JSON format
$authkey = file_get_contents("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?client_id=".$client_id."&client_secret=".$secret."&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=".$redirect."&code=".$_GET['code']);
//We then need to decode it and store that key in a variable 
$auth = json_decode($authkey,true);
$access_token = $auth['access_token'];
//we then look up whatever endpoint of the api we want
$fsUser = file_get_contents("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self?oauth_token=".$access_token);
$user = json_decode($fsUser, true);
// $name = $decoded_userinfo['response']['user']['firstName'];
}
?>
```

When I `var_dump $fsUser` I get `bool(false)`

I have var_dump every variable with no issues till I get to `$fsUser` I can not get past this part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to use the version number (v) with your request.

Like this

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&v=20140806&m=foursquare
```

See documentation here.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning